# observable collection in async method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-8, async-await

Hello friends i am getting very strange problem by using **ObservableCollection** in an **async** method in my windows store app. I am trying to add items in an ObservableCollection in an async method it is working fine if i define the ObservableCollection above a line where await keyword is but i initialize below this line it is not working. i have made sample for this problem. 
my xaml code is..

```
<Page
x:Class="observableCollectionTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:observableCollectionTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" Background="Pink" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="200" Height="200" Background="Red" >
                    <Button Content="click me" Name="btn" ></Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

my mainpage backhand working code is..

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> SomeCollection { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        FillCollection();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public async Task FillCollection()
    {
        SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(); // it is working..
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.co.in/");

        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");

    }
```

my mainpage backhand FillCollection code that is not working..

```
 public async Task FillCollection()
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.co.in/");
        SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(); // this is not working
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");
        SomeCollection.Add("asd");

    }
```

i am not getting why is this happening. i am missing some concept here please tell me..any kind of help or suggestion is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lacking property change event firing from your `SomeCollection` property - see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209899) on how to implement that.

The reason it is needed is that the part of your `FillCollection` method before async is executed before you assign `DataContext` property and the other half after web request is finished. So in your not working example the `View` does not know that whole collection was changed.

On the other hand consider what you are loosing assigning new instance of `ObservableCollection` on every list refresh (you want to refresh it at some point?). The underlying of this class is to provide UI way to optimize refreshing of items in  `ItemsControl`s by knowing which elements where added/removed/moved if you crate a new collection whole `ListView` will be rerendered which can be expensive. I suggest to move your assignment to constructor before `FillCollection` call for code clarity reasons and handle content change nicely - it is more work for you but if view is complicated it is worth it.